# What validation and sanitization do I need on my graphql server?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, graphql

My server is using the following technologies: Node.js, Express, GraphQL, JWT, MongoDB, Mongoose

Currently, I just have users, with the ability to create, delete, update, and log in to accounts, as well as view all users' usernames, useful for search.

For authentication, I'm using JWT, Hashed passwords, and using middleware to verify the tokens and provide users' information into graphql context for use by my resolvers.

I understand that I need security at multiple levels, so I'll outline what I have and maybe you guys can guide me in the direction of what I'm missing.

Mongoose: Default type validators, required, etc.

Mongoose-validator: custom validators

- Full Name: Characters, hyphens, spaces, apostrophes only
- Username: alphanumeric, underscore, hyphen and period only, between 4 and 24 chars
- Email: Valid email using mongoose-validator isEmail validator
- Password: 8+ characters, at least one lowercase, uppercase, number
- Birthday: is a date object and is at least 18 years in the past.

My specific questions are:

- Do I need to use express-sanitizer with this? If so, will it affect special characters in passwords?
- Am I missing any specific type of validation, or is there a checklist for what I should be doing to protect my server?

Also, any recommendations would be appreciated!

Comment: I have the exact same setup on a project im building so this would also help me